# CSS image / background scaling

Tags: css

**Setup:** I have this [website](http://www.acceleratedfreelance.com/dev/) with a top-header image that needs to resize properly depending on screen-size. This is the code I'm using:

HTML:

```
<img class="header-background" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/header.png';?>" alt="Header" />
```

CSS:

```
.header-background {
left: 0;
margin: auto;
right: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 91;
width: 100%;
margin-top: -35px;
}
```

**Problem:** The image size is 1900x227 pixels and I need it to resize properly depending on the resolution of each user.

This is how it supposed to look like. The blue top should remain the same on every resolution.

Would it be easier to replace the image with a CSS background / shape?

[image]

Comment: Is the problem that e.g. when a user resizes their browser, this happens: http://s8.postimage.org/vds0b7ljp/Capture.png

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.

Comment: Is it just the image height? or is it that all of page drops off?

Comment: Just the image height...

Comment: You can add a static height value like `height:200px`. (Thats what I have found that works best on my computer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a static height like `height:200px`.

(Thats what I have found that works best on my computer).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do here is use Media Queries with min/max-height & relational values as well.

ex.:

```
@media all and(max-width: 980px) and (max-height: 980px){
    .headerImage{
        width:8em;
        height:90%;
    }
}
```

More information on media queries: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Useful Tool to Convert Pixel Values to ems: http://pxtoem.com/